# How to get Mac OS to remember previous auth. from my executable file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, sudo, password, c

I'm writing a tiny unix executable file that changes my macbook's system time manually. Of course, this requires a password, and so I used the system() function to interface with the terminal and change the date using echo and sudo.

See below:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    // Retrieve password:
    printf("Enter Sudo Password:\n");

    char *pswrd;
    pswrd = getpass("Password: ");
    char strA[512];

    // Instruction to manually change the date:
    char *strA1 = "echo \"";
    char *strA2 = "\" | sudo -S date 020821002014";

    // Stitch fields into one string:
    strcat(strA, strA1);
    strcat(strA, pswrd);
    strcat(strA, strA2);

    // Run string in Terminal:
    system(strA);
}
```

You can create a Unix executable to test.

In terminal line, it is equivalent to: `Sudo date 020821002014`

**> Anyway, my question:**

> I don't like that every time I run the executable file, I have to
>   enter a password. Does anyone have suggestions for a way to input the
>   admin password once and have my MacBook recognize the executable in
>   future so I just have to click on the executable and change the date
>   effortlessly.

Oh, and I only picked the date because it typically requires a password, but this would of-course generalize to other administrator instructions.

Things I've considered:

> 1. Using root superuser, but it seems overkill - there must be another way
> 2. Writing password into .c code directly, but that sounds sketchy, and doesn't scale easily for multiple users

Comment: A C program is _very rarely_ called "a script".  "Script" is usually used for programs written in interpreted languages.

Comment: Thank you for that point @Kusalananda, what is a more appropriate synonym for .c file? I'll edit my post accordingly.

Comment: Just make a script that runs `sudo date 020821002014`. Sudo caches credentials per terminal based on user policy. The stuff you're doing is unecessary an error prone (`getpass` shouldn't be used and your quoting of the password is brittle). There shouldn't be a need for any of it.

Comment: @McMath Well, I would call it the source code and I would call the compiled executable "the executable" or "the binary".

Answer (score 0):

Another method (that does not leave the password lying around nor expose it to various process listing and diagnostic tools) would be to set a `NOPASSWD` entry in the `sudo` configuration file that allows only the `date` command to be run, possibly an exact `date` command:

```
fixmeyourusernamehere ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/date 020821002014
```

with this set at the bottom of the `/etc/sudoers` file (better edited with `sudo visudo`, though) then the user `fixmeyourusernamehere` should be able to run 'sudo date 020821002014`without a password, but not any other commands (unless the`sudo` configuration allows them other commands).